# Ctrl+C sends EOFError once after cancelling process

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, input, interrupt

I'm making a very basic command line utility using python, and I'm trying to set it up such that the user has the ability to interrupt any running operation during execution with Ctrl+C, and exit the program by sending an EOF with Ctrl+Z. However, I've been fighting with this frustrating issue for the last day where after cancelling a running operation with a `KeyboardInterrupt`, pressing Ctrl+C a second time sends an `EOFError` instead of a `KeyboardInterrupt`, which causes the program to exit. Hitting Ctrl+C subsequent times sends `KeyboardInterrupt`'s as usual, except until I input any command or an empty line, where an additional `KeyboardInterrupt` is sent instead of the input I give. After doing so, hitting Ctrl+C again will send an `EOFError` again, and continues from there. Here's a minimal example of code demonstrating my issue;

```py
import time

def parse(inp):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(inp)
    if inp == 'e':
        return 'exit'

while True:
    try:
        user_in = input("> ").strip()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
        print(e.__class__.__name__)
        continue

    if not user_in:
        continue

    try:
        if parse(user_in) == 'exit':
            break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Cancelled")
```

And here's some sample output of my code;

```
>
>
>
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
>
>
> ^Z
EOFError
> ^Z
EOFError
> ^Z
EOFError
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
>
> ^Z
EOFError
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
>
```

As you can see, when hitting Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z, or a blank line, the prompt responds as you would expect with each error appropriately. However, if I run a command and try cancelling it during execution by hitting Ctrl+C;

```
> test
Cancelled
>
>
>
> EOFError
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
KeyboardInterrupt
>
>
> EOFError
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
KeyboardInterrupt
>
>
>
```

I only hit Ctrl+C and Enter in the above example; I first hit enter to send several blank lines, then hit Ctrl+C, which sends an `EOFError` at first. Hitting Ctrl+C mutliple times afterwards then sends `KeyboardInterrupt`'s correctly. Afterwards, sending a blank line instead then sends a `KeyboardInterrupt`, and subsequent blank lines entered are received normally. This functionality is repeated onward from the program's execution there.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: **Adding detail:** the issue occurs when run via the Windows 10 command line and does not occur when using the Bash shell on Windows 10.

Comment: This is a really interesting issue. I was able to reproduce it. I'll dig into it tomorrow, why it's happening!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So. You've found a pretty old Python [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue26531). It's to do with the async nature of keyboard interrupts, AND how if you send a `KeyboardInterrupt` to Python while hanging, and it doesn't respond to the interrupt, the second interrupt will raise the even stronger `EOFError`. However, it seems, that these two collide, if you have an async `KeyboardInterrupt` caught followed by an input with a second `KeyboardInterrupt`, there will some stuff left in some buffer, which triggered `EOFError`.

I know this isn't a great explanation, nor is it very clear. However, it allows for a pretty simple fix. Let the buffer to catch up with all the async interrupts, and than start waiting for an input:

```py
import time

def parse(inp):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(inp)
    if inp == 'e':
        return 'exit'

while True:
    try:
        user_in = input("> ").strip()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
        print(e.__class__.__name__)
        continue

    if not user_in:
        continue

    try:
        if parse(user_in) == 'exit':
            break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Cancelled")
        time.sleep(0.1)    # This is the only line that's added
```

Now doing the same actions you did produces this:

```
> test
Cancelled
>
>
>
>
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
>
> KeyboardInterrupt
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe the fix is that simple.

Comment: Got a small question about this solution. Is the `print("Cancelled")` important here? Or would it still work if the `time.sleep` call was the only thing in the `except` block?